# build app that use libraries installed from msys2 with pacman

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msys2

I tried to build my app that uses `glib-2.0` with *Visual Studio*.

The `glib-2.0` was installed with `pacman` from `msys2`, so I haven't got `glib-2.0.lib` but I have `glib-2.0.a`

When I set `glib-2.0.a` and `intl.a` in *Additional Dependencies* from *Visual Studio 2013*, I got this errors:

> Erreur    2   error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu ___chkstk_ms  C:\Users\julien\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\m\m\libintl.a(loadmsgcat.o)   m
>
> Erreur    66  error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu __imp_getsockopt  C:\Users\julien\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\m\m\libglib-2.0.a(giowin32.o) m

etc etc ...

I have set `intl.a` too because `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 --msvc-syntax` returns:

> /libpath:C:/msys64/mingw64/lib.lib glib-2.0.lib intl.lib

What I have to do to build my app?

Comment: This is **not** a MinGW issue. MSYS2 is completely unrelated to MinGW. Please remove the "mingw" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build GLIB with MSVC.